# R, searching specific size words in text, nchar function

Tags: r, string

I have a long text and I counted letters in every single word of it, now I want to show the shortest and the longest words. I used:

```
words<-strsplit(text," ") 
nchar(words[[1]])
w<-factor(nchar(words[[1]]))
table(w)
```

and I got a table with amount of words of specific length. And now, for example I know that the longest word has 19 letters, but how can I find and show that one word from whole text?

EDIT: and how to show for example every 5-letters word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `which.max` to find longest word

```
words[[1]][which.max(nchar(words[[1]]))]
```

---

If you want to find all 5-letter words, try below

```
words[[1]][nchar(words[[1]])==5]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this one works! But now (post edit) what if I want to show for example all 5-letters words?

Comment: @camouro See my udpate

Comment: It's much easier than I thought. Thanks!